# Temperature Converter Issues

Tags: jquery

Simple question. How is this not working? It's a temperature converter, with parts for both F2C and C2F. I'm a newb to programming in general.

HTML:

```
Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:
Enter Celsius Value:
<input id="valToConvertToF" type="text" size="7">

Farenheit Value:
<input id="result1" type="text" size="7" readonly />
<button id="fButton" type="button">Convert!</button>

Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius:
Enter Farenheit Value:
<input id="valToConvertToC" type="text" size="7">

Celsius Value:
<input id="result2" type="text" size="7" readonly />
<button id="cButton" type="button">Convert!</button>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    /*celsius to f*/
    var inputVal1 = $("#valToConvertToF");
    var outputVal1 = $("#result1");
    var commandButton1 = $("#fButton");

    function efIt()
        {
        // read value entered by user
        // convert it from string to number
        var initialVal1 = parseFloat(inputVal1.value);

        // bulletproof
        if(isNaN(initialVal1))
        {
            window.alert("Enter a valid number! \nTry again!");
            inputVal1.value = "";
            outputVal1.value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            // calculate it, to 2 decimal points
            var calculatedVal1 = ( (9/5) *initialVal1 + 32 ).toFixed(2); 
            // display square
            outputVal1.text(calculatedVal1);

        }

        }
            // when referring to function, NO PARENS
            commandButton1.click(efIt);

    /*next*/        

    /*farenheit to c*/
    var inputVal2 = $("#valToConvertToC");
    var outputVal2 = $("#result2");
    var commandButton2 = $("#cButton");

    function cIt()
        {
        // read value entered by user
        // convert it from string to number
        var initialVal2 = parseFloat(inputVal2.value);

        // bulletproof
        if(isNaN(initialVal2))
        {
            window.alert("Enter a valid number! \nTry again!");
            inputVal2.value = "";
            outputVal2.value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            // calculate it, to 2 decimal points
            var calculatedVal2 = ( (5/9) *(initialVal2 - 32)).toFixed(2); 
            // display square
            outputVal2.text(calculatedVal2);

        }

        }
            // when referring to function, NO PARENS
            commandButton2.click(cIt);  

});
```

Comment: What does it do that's different than what you expect?  "Not working" isn't a lot to go on...

Comment: If you're not going to tell us what's wrong, at least post a jsfiddle/jsbin.

Comment: $(yourInput).val() to get the value using jQuery.

Comment: Salvaged your post a bit, removed all irrelevant code. It only makes it more difficult to read/understand, and adds no extra value. Css has nothing to do with javascript, so removed that too.

Comment: Fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Bke65/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery object doesn't have a `value` property, use the `val` method:

```
var initialVal1 = parseFloat(inputVal1.val());
```

and:

```
inputVal1.val("");
outputVal1.val("");
```

and:

```
var initialVal2 = parseFloat(inputVal2.val());
```

and:

```
inputVal2.val("");
outputVal2.val("");
```

Don't use the `text` method for setting the value of the input, use the `val` method:

```
outputVal1.val(calculatedVal1);
```

and:

```
outputVal2.val(calculatedVal2);
```

Comment: or change the variable to the following: `var inputVal1 = $("#valToConvertToF")[0];`, now you can use `.value`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*celsius to f*/
  $("#fButton").click(function()
    {
     var inputVal1 = $("#valToConvertToF");
     var outputVal1 = $("#result1");    
    // read value entered by user
    // convert it from string to number
     var initialVal1 = parseFloat(inputVal1.val());
    // bulletproof
    if(isNaN(initialVal1))
    {
        window.alert("Enter a valid number! \nTry again!");
        inputVal1.val("");
        outputVal1.val("");
    }
    else
    {
        // calculate it, to 2 decimal points
        var calculatedVal1 = ( (9/5) *initialVal1 + 32 ).toFixed(2); 
        // display square
        outputVal1.val(calculatedVal1);
    }

    }
    );
```

#### Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Bke65/